# Searching for a String in Array<Any>

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

I'm pretty new to Swift. I have a DB connection to my app and all of the query results are stored in an Array of type Any as I've created one function to pass any queries.

I am now looking to search into this array for a specific string (here for example the email).

```swift
let Array = [1, Doe, John, john_doe@gmail.com, jdoe, t, 03/11/2022 15:00:00, nil, 1]

let stringToSearch:String = "John_doe@gmail.com"

if contains(itemsArray, stringToSearch) {
    NSLog("Term Exists")
}
else {
    NSLog("Can't find term")
}
```

I've looked at several options, but my main issue is how to move out from `Array<Any>` to `String`.

Comment: Retagged because this isn't SwiftUI -- it's just Swift

Comment: Makes no sense because your first line is not legal so I don't even know how you would form the array to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line is total nonsense; no such array can ever be formed. But let's pretend you mean this:

```
let array = [1, "Doe", "John", "john_doe@gmail.com", "jdoe", "t", "03/11/2022 15:00:00", nil, 1]
```

Then you can say

```
let stringMembersOfArray = array.compactMap { $0 as? String }
```

And now you have just the strings, and can see what that contains.

Comment: thanks Matt for the comment, this code sample is simplified but basically the array is formed with the query result (here an array resulting from a Select command in Postgresql

Comment: I stand by my answer and my comment.

Comment: ok, understand your answer/comment, I need to review my previous function that return the Array<Any>. due to this my array's data is not defined as string (this is why it is not showing the brackets) hence the issue and the empty array when using .compactMap

Comment: Wouldn't a `contains(where:)` be more efficient: Avoid two loops? But as the comments says, if `array.compactMap { $0 as? String }` is empty, it's strange, and might need to show what's the method do populate it, and what's the real types of each values...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `[Any]` array to get just the values with a type of `String`.

```
let record: [Any] = ... // the record with lots of values of different types in it
let strings = record.compactMap { $0 as? String }
if let strings.contains(stringToSearch) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```

BTW - do not name a variable `Array`. That's confusing with the `Array` type. Plus, variable names should begin with lowercase letters.